# PHP Wordpress string concatenation not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress, string, svg

The following:

```
class="<?php the_field('icon','service-category_'.$term->term_id) ?>">
```

makes it:

```
class="icon-ico-1"
```

But when I do the following:

```
<?php $iconpath = 'images/'.the_field('icon','service-category_'.$term->term_id).'.svg.php'; ?>
```

It doesn't calculate the `'icon-ico-1'` and instead gives the following path:

```
images/.svg.php
```

Which is obviously not correct. I want it to be:

```
images/icon-ico-1.svg.php
```

Comment: Any errors in log? Seems like you are using it in the place where `the_field()` function is not defined properly. Are those two examples the same file / the same scope?

Answer (score 0):

Try storing your fields as variables and echoing the string

```html
<?php 
  $icon = get_field('icon');
  $servicecategory = get_field('service-category_');
  $newterm = $term->term_id;
  
  echo 'images/'.$icon.'-'.$servicecategory.'-'.$newterm;
?>
```